# not sure why this jquery post isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-post

I have the following jquery:

```
  var xj=[{"name":"person","id":1},{"name":"jack", "id":2}];
  $.post('/hex-jt/locations',xj , function(data){
    console.log("this posted");
  },'json');
```

which seems like it should be ok. But it is passed like this to my rails app:

[image]

Any idea what is going on with this?

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: Instead of an image, please give us the complete text of the error in the post. A person who searches on Google won't be able to find the text of your error if it's in an image.

Comment: why close? what the OP posted is enough to answer. jquery.post() wants a PlainObject while he is passing an array: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling [`jquery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) with bad argument data, passing an array instead of a String or a [`PlainObject`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject).

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )

data
Type: PlainObject or String
A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
```

You can for instance modify it like this, wrapping the array in an object:

```
xj={"users":[{"name":"person","id":1},{"name":"jack", "id":2}]};
```

Comment: thx, I had noticed when I wrapped it, it worked; didn't realize it was a requirement. Live an learn.